# The attribute ['mean'] is not found in nx.nodes (networkx for python), is there a substitute for that?

Tags: python, attributes, networkx, mean

I tried to use the `'mean'` attribute of the graph nodes, where `g = nx.Graph()`. When I enter part of the code including the `g.nodes[u]['mean']`, the jupyter notebook gave me the error message:

```
      5     nodes['mean'] = nodes['total color'] / nodes['pixel count']
      6     for u, v in g.edges():
----> 7         d = g.nodes[u]['mean'] - g.nodes[v]['mean']
      8         g[u][v]['weight'] = np.linalg.norm(d)
      9 

KeyError: 'mean'
```

Does anyone know if there is a similar substitute for this deprecated attribute? I also couldn't find the list of attributes on line. Thanks!

Comment: Could you add how are you creating the graph and defining the attributes?

Comment: you could use `print()` to see what you have in `g.nodes[v]`, Maybe `g.nodes` and `nodes` (which you use in `nodes['mean'] = ...`) are not the same elements.

Comment: I simply used a script from "Elegant SciPy: The Art of Scientific Python" written by Juan Nunez-Iglesias etc. Apparently they used the older version of networkx. I am just curious what could be substitute for the attribute 'mean' in a nx.Graph() object.

Comment: By default the nodes are not given any attributes.  The attribute `mean` is only defined for a node if you've somehow assigned a value to it.